# Why won't my Canon 60D take more than one photo with the internal flash, without closing it manually?

Tags: troubleshooting, canon-60d, popup-flash

If the internal flash is raised, when I try to take a photo nothing happens; the shutter do not open and the focus too do not change while half-pressing the button. *No error* is displayed when this happens

After I manually close the internal flash, everything goes back to normal... I can take many photos while the flash is closed. The camera works normally until I take a photo that requires the flash (auto mode), the flash rises and the focus adjusts then the camera takes the photo... but after that the same problem occurs.

Comment: It really sounds defective and the problem is probably in the flash unit, the capacitor never registers fully charged, so the camera wait indefinitely. Check in the menu system is you have an option like *Release Shutter while Charging* or *Shutter-Priority*. It exists on some cameras but I don't have a 60D. If you have it, that should confirm the problem.

Comment: In the flash menu settings on the camera, do you have wireless set?

Comment: @inkista do you mean wether the wireless set is enabled or not?

Comment: @Itai I am not sure if such options exist, I do not have the camera with me now. lets assume they do exist, can I use them to override this problem? such that the camera will always shoot evet if it thinks the flash is not fully charged yet.

Comment: @BlueTile - Yes, that is exactly what those options are for. The assumption is that the flash may not be fully charged when a you want to take a shot, so use whatever charge is there anyway. Of course, the best if your flash is not working it to repair it or turn it off because when you use these options, the resulting exposure *may* be off as it is not clear whether your flash is not charging or it is just not sending the charge full signal. You may try dialing negative Flash Compensation (FC) just to see if it has an impact.

Comment: @Itai many thanks. I will try that and come back with the results.

Comment: When you raise the flash, [does it raise all the way](http://www.tutorialgeek.net/2013/02/how-to-fix-popup-flash-on-your-camera.html)? and have you checked that [the microswitch in the hotshoe is cleared](http://www.conraderb.com/flashrepair/#replace) (i.e., not pressed in to signal a hotshoe flash is mounted).

Comment: @inkista If the microswitch is not cleared, the camera would not have taken the first picture. Unless I misunderstood you.

Comment: @BlueTile if the microswitch is engaged, the camera simply thinks there's an external flash (speedlite) mounted on the hotshoe--it would probably still take the picture, but the pop-up flash wouldn't go off--it actually shouldn't pop-up in that case, but figured it was at least worth checking.

Comment: @inkista yes. though it IS worth checking. I will.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this happens when people don't give it time to recharge.  It may be that simple.  If you are giving it time to recharge and it gives you a charged indicator light but still won't fire, then it is faulty.  Send it away for repair.

Answer (score -3):

I looked up the 60d flash settings online.
Looks like you can actually disable the built in flash in the menu! So first check you're set to "enable!"
Next select whether you want manual or TTL control and you (if this is the problem) should be good to go!

Comment: I do not understand, why would I disable the flash?